# Javascript not working just by me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>bla</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#left").children(".thumb").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $("#preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $("#preview").hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="left">
    <img src="http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg" class="thumb" />
    <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/36522-Tabby-kitten-white-background.jpg" class="thumb" />
    <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/11406-Ginger-kitten-rolling-on-its-back-white-background.jpg" class="thumb" />
    <img id="preview" />
</div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
#preview 
{
    background:#333;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

All that from: http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/sd3ouo9g/ But it's not working by me like there, what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and deleted all cookies and all that?  Have you done a ctrl-f5?  Can other's see this work?  If so it could be the browser you are using.

Comment: you need to add your script in a [dom ready handler](learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sd3ouo9g/1/ - similar to your code(not working) - see the second dropdown in the left panel

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sd3ouo9g/2/ - working after adding the script in dom ready handler

Comment: Thanks Arun now it's working, i'm new in js ^^ PHP is much easier for me

Answer (score 3):

try putting it inside a `$(document).ready` like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").children(".thumb").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $("#preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $("#preview").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing DOM elements before the page is fully loaded. The only reason that code works in the JSFiddle you referenced is that they selected the `onLoad` option:

[image]

As `Yourness` suggests, use a DOM ready handler (which the JSFiddle `onLoad` does for you).

The shortcut versions of `$(document).ready(function(){...});` are:

### `$(function(){...});`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#left").children(".thumb").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $("#preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).show();
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $("#preview").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or the more robust version (which scopes a local `$` at the same time):

### `jQuery(function($){...});`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#left").children(".thumb").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $("#preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).show();
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $("#preview").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Option 3:

*Or you can simply put your existing `<script>` block at the bottom of the `body` element (after the elements it references).*

```
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg" class="thumb" />
        <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/36522-Tabby-kitten-white-background.jpg" class="thumb" />
        <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/11406-Ginger-kitten-rolling-on-its-back-white-background.jpg" class="thumb" />
        <img id="preview" />
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("#left").children(".thumb").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $("#preview").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).show();
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $("#preview").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```